# Need app to detect nfc, both when running and when closed

Tags: android, nfc

I'm currently building an application for Android using NFC-technology. The NFC-part is being used to log in to the app. So here's the deal: i want the app to respond differently when detecting the tag when it is already running. Here are the two situations:

1) When the user scans a tag with a specific URI, the app launches, loading the URI into the username-textfield. User then enters his password, presses login, and voila, magic. This part works fine.

2) Now, i also want the app to be launched from the app-list, showing a login form. No problem, i use a different activity for that. But now, how do i make some sort of custom Event Listener that makes the app wait for the tag to be scanned, and then puts the URI into the username-field without, and here it comes, launching the app again, as described in situation 1?

Hope you guys can help me out here, sorry for the long text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use foreground mode for your open activity and it will be able to receieve all NDEF messages (from tag or beam). Check boilerplate project in [this](http://code.google.com/p/ndef-tools-for-android/) project (shameless plug).

Comment: Check ;) Spent all day doing exactly this. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I have the same problem my app doesnt detect NFC when app is closed, but i could not understand your answer enough, could you please explain clearer??

Comment: now i am using NFCAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(Activity, PindingIntent, IntentFilter, techList) in onResume but my app only detect NFC when it opened

Comment: You need to specify a filter in the Manifest.xml to get NFC detected when app is not started (unless the tag has a AAR)

Answer (score 0):

Your application itself simply needs to be aware of it's own current state and respond to the scanned tag accordingly

Comment: Yes i figured that out... but what happens now is that whenever i scan a tag, a new instance of the above mentioned situation 1 is built.